# Remove an attribute set in Yii Model

Tags: php, yii, ldap

I work with Yii 1.x integrated with an LDAP database and while I was developing an feature for external user access to IT resources: Domain (to authenticate Windows/Linux external users) and Wi-fi (access to use), or both.

I faced a scenario where I need to remove an attribute which I earlier set in the model: for security reasons, I populate the model with all data expect the main  flags like **sambaAcctFlags, disabledAccount and shadowExpire** whom grant real access to resources: SAMBA in Domain and RUCKUS in Wi-fi.

The main problem is when I create a model record, I set the attribute **disabledAccount** - which when not there grants access to Wi-fi, but when its set the RUCKUS refuses auth - and now I cannot remove this value from model when the user has not selected the checkbox and so I tried to use `unset($model->disabledAccount)` and it didn't work. I have seen some suggestions that replace the variable with a null value but with my LDAP Yii' extensions, this will throw an LDAP error when saving the disabledAccount attribute.

Any light what could be done?

```
                $model->shadowexpire = time();
                $model->sambaAcctFlags = '[UD]';
                $model->disabledaccount = date('YmdHis\Z');

                foreach ($_POST['checkbox_acessos'] as $access ) {
                    switch ($access) {
                        case 'C': // Verify if the user has set Domain Access to user
                            $model->sambaAcctFlags = '[U]';   //Change flag from Deactivate to Activate
                            break;
                        case 'W': // Verify if the user has set Wi-fi to user
                            unset($model->disabledaccount); //this is the main problem**
                            echo "Wi-fi Granted!";
                            break;           
                    }
                }

                $model->shadowExpire = strtotime($validade->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'));
                // Date when Expire Unix based systems access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get your problem correctly, your sentences were incomplete, anyway
if you want to save the default value that you defined before in your database, replace `unset` method with `unsetAttributes()`.

In this case:

```
$model->unsetAttributes(['disabledAccount']);
```

Comment: Already corrected, could you give it another try? Also, I'm using Yii 1.x not Yii 2.

Comment: Did you test the solution I gave to you?

Comment: @DaniloDavanso, if I remember correctly, `unsetAttributes` method is for Yii 1! I

Comment: Tested and dind't work. Gave me an error 500 in this line. Saying 'Invalid Argument for foreach();"

Comment: `foreach` error is irrelevant for our problem here! because we didn't change the array that comes into foreach in your code. If you can, please share your controller or error logs, because I can't figure out what happens inside your project...

Comment: Hamid Yousefi. I resolved the problem since this approach would lead me to change my extension in Yii with LDAP. So I changed foreach to in_array function and in false scenario (when Wi-Fi access is not set, then you add to the model) and this worked.

Comment: Used your function in another context and solved my problem. Come here to update and give the answer